Upgrading from Spring Boot 3.1 => 3.2 breaks Azure Kubernetes JDBC setup
Anyone coming across The server requested password-based authentication, but no password was provided by plugin null when moving from Spring Boot 3.1.x to Spring Boot 3.2?
Moving from any Spring Boot 3.1 release (tested 3.1.4 as well as latest 3.1.10) to any Spring Boot 3.2 release (tried 3.2.5 and 3.2.0) will give us the error above when deploying to our Kubernetes cluster in Azure. The strange thing is that we have upgraded to Spring Boot 3.2.4 in several other Gradle projects with Spring Azure JDBC integrations as well, without seeing this issue.
I am assuming this is causing by Spring Cloud Azure, using passwordless token-based JDBC authorisation, as I have no issues running against a local database.
Working database setup
This setup is working (Spring Azure and Spring Boot 3.1.x). It connects to our database using the passwordless Spring Azure setup, using a runtime id that is mapped to a group role in Postgres.
spring:
  datasource:
    driver-class-name: org.postgresql.Driver
    url: jdbc:postgresql://our-namespace-01.postgres.database.azure.com:5432/my-database?currentSchema=my-db-schema
    username: our-postgres-runtime-id

    azure:
      passwordless-enabled: true
      credential:
        managed-identity-enabled: true
        client-id: ${cf.runtime.clientid} # replaced by kconf (Kubernetes)


Dependencies
Running gradle dependencies gives a 34KB output, so I put that in this pastebin. This is the relevant sections from build.gradle:
plugins {
    id 'io.spring.dependency-management' version '1.1.4'
    id 'jacoco'
    id 'java'
    id 'maven-publish'
    id 'org.springframework.boot' version '3.2.5'
}

java {
    toolchain {
        languageVersion = JavaLanguageVersion.of(17)
    }
}

apply plugin: 'application'

configurations {
    implementation.exclude group: "org.springframework.boot", module: "spring-boot-starter-logging"
    implementation.exclude group: 'ch.qos.logback', module: 'logback-classic'
}

dependencies {
    implementation 'com.datadoghq:dd-trace-api:1.33.0' // log trace, span, correlation id
    implementation 'com.fasterxml.woodstox:woodstox-core:6.6.2'
    implementation 'io.micrometer:micrometer-registry-prometheus'
    implementation 'jakarta.activation:jakarta.activation-api:2.1.3'
    implementation 'jakarta.validation:jakarta.validation-api:3.1.0-M2'
    implementation 'jakarta.xml.bind:jakarta.xml.bind-api:4.0.2'
    implementation 'org.apache.commons:commons-collections4:4.5.0-M1'
    implementation 'org.apache.commons:commons-lang3:3.14.0'
    implementation 'org.postgresql:postgresql:42.7.3'
    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-actuator'
    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-data-jpa'
    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-jdbc'
    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-log4j2'
    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web'
    implementation 'org.springframework.cloud:spring-cloud-starter-sleuth:3.1.11' // log trace, span, correlation id
    implementation 'org.springframework.kafka:spring-kafka'
    implementation 'com.fasterxml.jackson.dataformat:jackson-dataformat-xml:2.17.0'
    implementation 'com.ibm.mq:mq-jms-spring-boot-starter:3.2.4'

    implementation platform('com.azure.spring:spring-cloud-azure-dependencies:5.11.0')
    implementation 'com.azure.spring:spring-cloud-azure-starter-jdbc-postgresql'

    implementation(
        /** Dependencies for batch processing */
        'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-validation',
        'org.springframework.batch:spring-batch-core',
        'com.zaxxer:HikariCP',
        'org.springframework.batch:spring-batch-test'
    )
    implementation project(path: ':external-apis')

    runtimeOnly 'javax.xml.bind:jaxb-api:2.4.0-b180830.0359'

    testImplementation 'org.apache.kafka:kafka_2.13:3.7.0:test'
    testImplementation 'org.apache.kafka:kafka-clients:3.7.0:test'
    testImplementation 'org.testcontainers:postgresql:1.19.7'
    testImplementation 'org.testcontainers:testcontainers:1.19.7'

    testImplementation('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-test') {
        exclude group: 'org.junit.vintage', module: 'junit-vintage-engine'
    }

    testImplementation ('org.springframework.kafka:spring-kafka-test') {
        // needed if downgrading to Apache Kafka 2.8.1
        exclude group: 'org.apache.zookeeper', module: 'zookeeper'
    }
}

Spring Boot 3 attempt at upgrading
Full build.gradle file below:
import org.gradle.api.tasks.testing.logging.TestExceptionFormat
import org.gradle.api.tasks.testing.logging.TestLogEvent

plugins {
    id 'io.spring.dependency-management' version '1.1.5'
    id 'jacoco'
    id 'java'
    id 'org.springframework.boot' version '3.3.0'
}

java {
    toolchain {
        languageVersion = JavaLanguageVersion.of(17)
    }
}

apply plugin: 'application'

jar {
    enabled = true
}

ext {
    jacocoToolVersion = '0.8.7'
}

configurations {
    implementation.exclude group: "org.springframework.boot", module: "spring-boot-starter-logging"
    implementation.exclude group: 'ch.qos.logback', module: 'logback-classic'
}

dependencies {
    implementation 'com.datadoghq:dd-trace-api:1.34.0' // log trace, span, correlation id
    implementation 'com.fasterxml.woodstox:woodstox-core:6.6.2'
    implementation 'io.micrometer:micrometer-registry-prometheus'
    implementation 'jakarta.activation:jakarta.activation-api:2.1.3'
    implementation 'jakarta.validation:jakarta.validation-api:3.1.0'
    implementation 'jakarta.xml.bind:jakarta.xml.bind-api:4.0.2'
    implementation 'org.apache.commons:commons-collections4:4.5.0-M1'
    implementation 'org.apache.commons:commons-lang3:3.14.0'
    implementation 'org.postgresql:postgresql:42.7.3'
    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-actuator'
    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-data-jpa'
    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-jdbc'
    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-log4j2'
    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web'
    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-validation'
    implementation 'org.springframework.batch:spring-batch-core'
    implementation 'org.springframework.kafka:spring-kafka'
    implementation platform('org.springframework.kafka:spring-kafka-bom:3.2.0')

    implementation 'com.zaxxer:HikariCP'

    implementation platform('com.fasterxml.jackson:jackson-bom:2.17.1')
    implementation 'com.fasterxml.jackson.dataformat:jackson-dataformat-xml'
    implementation 'com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-databind'
    implementation 'com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-core'
    implementation 'com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-annotations'
    implementation 'com.ibm.mq:mq-jms-spring-boot-starter:3.2.4'

    implementation platform('com.azure.spring:spring-cloud-azure-dependencies:5.13.0')
    implementation 'com.azure.spring:spring-cloud-azure-starter-jdbc-postgresql'

    implementation project(path: ':external-apis')

    runtimeOnly 'javax.xml.bind:jaxb-api:2.4.0-b180830.0359'

    testImplementation 'org.apache.kafka:kafka_2.13'
    testImplementation 'org.apache.kafka:kafka-clients'
    testImplementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-testcontainers'
    testImplementation 'org.testcontainers:testcontainers-bom:1.19.8'
    testImplementation 'org.testcontainers:testcontainers'
    testImplementation 'org.testcontainers:postgresql'
    testImplementation "org.testcontainers:junit-jupiter"

    testImplementation('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-test') {
        exclude group: 'org.junit.vintage', module: 'junit-vintage-engine'
        exclude group: 'com.vaadin.external.google', module: 'android-json'
    }

    testImplementation('org.springframework.kafka:spring-kafka-test') {
        // needed if downgrading to Apache Kafka 2.8.1
        exclude group: 'org.apache.zookeeper', module: 'zookeeper'
    }
}

tasks.withType(Test) {
    jvmArgs += '--add-opens=java.base/java.math=ALL-UNNAMED'
}

tasks.withType(JavaExec) {
    jvmArgs += '--add-opens=java.base/java.math=ALL-UNNAMED'
}

test {
    //To exclude integration test run with gradlew build -Dtest.profile=UnitTest
    //To exclude slow tests: `gradlew build -Dtest.profile=fast`
    if (System.properties['test.profile'] == 'fast') {
        exclude '**/*ITest*'
        exclude '**/*IntegrationTest*'
        exclude '**/*RepositoryTest*'

        useJUnitPlatform {
            excludeTags "slow"
        }
    } else {
        useJUnitPlatform()
    }

    finalizedBy jacocoTestReport
    testLogging {
        events TestLogEvent.FAILED,
                TestLogEvent.PASSED,
                TestLogEvent.SKIPPED,
                TestLogEvent.STANDARD_OUT
        exceptionFormat TestExceptionFormat.FULL
        showExceptions true
        showCauses true
        showStackTraces true
    }
    reports {
        junitXml.required = true
    }
}

jacoco() {
    toolVersion = jacocoToolVersion
}

jacocoTestReport() {
    reports {
        html.required = true
        xml.required = true
        csv.required = true
    }
    afterEvaluate {
        getClassDirectories().setFrom(files(classDirectories.files.collect {
            fileTree(dir: it, exclude: ['**/*Application**',])
        }))
    }
}

Errors about beans not being eligible for processing
I also see these errors when running tests. Could they explain anything?
    11.06.2024 00:57:05,882 [CID:]  [Test worker] WARN  [egate$BeanPostProcessorChecker] - Bean 'jdbcConnectionDetails' of type [org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.jdbc.PropertiesJdbcConnectionDetails] is not eligible for getting processed by all BeanPostProcessors (for example: not eligible for auto-proxying). Is this bean getting eagerly injected into a currently created BeanPostProcessor [jobRegistryBeanPostProcessor]? Check the corresponding BeanPostProcessor declaration and its dependencies.
    11.06.2024 00:57:05,893 [CID:]  [Test worker] WARN  [egate$BeanPostProcessorChecker] - Bean 'dataSource' of type [com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource] is not eligible for getting processed by all BeanPostProcessors (for example: not eligible for auto-proxying). Is this bean getting eagerly injected into a currently created BeanPostProcessor [jobRegistryBeanPostProcessor]? Check the corresponding BeanPostProcessor declaration and its dependencies.
    11.06.2024 00:57:05,908 [CID:]  [Test worker] WARN  [egate$BeanPostProcessorChecker] - Bean 'spring.jpa-org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.orm.jpa.JpaProperties' of type [org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.orm.jpa.JpaProperties] is not eligible for getting processed by all BeanPostProcessors (for example: not eligible for auto-proxying). Is this bean getting eagerly injected into a currently created BeanPostProcessor [jobRegistryBeanPostProcessor]? Check the corresponding BeanPostProcessor declaration and its dependencies.
    11.06.2024 00:57:05,911 [CID:]  [Test worker] WARN  [egate$BeanPostProcessorChecker] - Bean 'spring.jpa.hibernate-org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.orm.jpa.HibernateProperties' of type [org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.orm.jpa.HibernateProperties] is not eligible for getting processed by all BeanPostProcessors (for example: not eligible for auto-proxying). Is this bean getting eagerly injected into a currently created BeanPostProcessor [jobRegistryBeanPostProcessor]? Check the corresponding BeanPostProcessor declaration and its dependencies.
    11.06.2024 00:57:05,913 [CID:]  [Test worker] WARN  [egate$BeanPostProcessorChecker] - Bean 'org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.jdbc.metadata.DataSourcePoolMetadataProvidersConfiguration$HikariPoolDataSourceMetadataProviderConfiguration' of type [org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.jdbc.metadata.DataSourcePoolMetadataProvidersConfiguration$HikariPoolDataSourceMetadataProviderConfiguration] is not eligible for getting processed by all BeanPostProcessors (for example: not eligible for auto-proxying). Is this bean getting eagerly injected into a currently created BeanPostProcessor [jobRegistryBeanPostProcessor]? Check the corresponding BeanPostProcessor declaration and its dependencies.
etc


What database runtime are you using? What's your JDBC URL look like?

Not sure if it would make a difference but helps at least with strange dependencies. Remove the 'jakarta.activation and jakarta.validation dependencies, as those are already pulled in other wise. I would suggest using spring-boot-starter-batch instead of individual Spring Batch modules (except for testing one). And I would use proper dependency management for cloud and azure by using platform for the dependencies for cloud and azure. As you nw run the possibility to get mixed dependencies.

@ArchitectJamie Added the database details.

@M.Deinum "I would use proper dependency management for cloud and azure by using platform for the dependencies for cloud and azure." Not sure what you mean by this. Any refs?

The spring-cloud-azure-dependencies is a bom containing the needed dependencies, which you shouldn't use for implementation but rather platform much like you would do a dependenciesManagement with an import scope dependency. The same for the regular Spring Cloud dependencies instead of specifying the version for a single starter.

@M.Deinum I am not actually sure what you mean here, as I seem to be doing exactly what you talk about. implementation platform 'the.dependen.cy:foo:123' is exactly how BOM based dependency management is supposed to be done, according to the docs and is what I have done above. ref https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/platforms.html#sub:bom_import

My bad I missed the platform bit here. Have you tried the 5.12.0 version of this dependency? Another thing is you have Spring Cloud Sleuth in there, this is pulling in Spring  Boot 2.6 dependencies and isn't compatible with Spring Boot 3.x (or newer Spring Cloud versions) so this is going to conflict at one point.

I have upgraded the azure dep to 5.13, removed spring sleuth, removed some redundant dependencies and tried upping to Spring Boot 3.3. Same issue. I pasted the full build.gradle above. Still get the weird "no password was provided by plugin null" message.

It seems as if someone else has posted an issue about this on the bug tracker: https://github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-java/issues/38631. I don't complain to understand it 100%, but it might be related to the bits above about "is not eligible for getting processed by ...", in case the order of bean init is a bit random.
